# Queue creation for MDBs in Wildfly

Tags: java, jms, wildfly, message-driven-bean, java-ee-8

I have such MDB in my application

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/TestQueue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "messageSelector", propertyValue = "source = 'client'")})
public class JmsReceiver implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        // .......
    }

}
```

The question is the way of queue creation. I remember that with Wildfly 16 it was enough simply to deploy application with MDB and the queue was available remotely with JNDI name `jms/queue/TestQueue` but with Wildfly 18 it starts to work only after I create the queue with proper name in server console.

How exactly the queue creation works in Wildfly and ActiveMQ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you add a jms destination definition xml file to your deployment. See https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Messaging+configuration for an example

Comment: Thank you. I see that it works if I do that but I want to have more detailed picture of how it works.